# Is there any python sdk support for Azure to create Virtual Network?

Tags: python-2.7, azure

I am trying to create Virtual network in azure using Azure Python Sdk.
I am using SDK Version 2.0.0a1.

But, I am not getting any support to create Virtual Network using python.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just to let you know... this isn't the place to be demanding answers "ASAP" - it's a community-driven site, with no SLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what, exactly, you mean when you say you aren't "getting any support to create Virtual Network" but...

Just take a look at the SDK source and you'll see that there are indeed classes and methods for managing virtual networks. Just peek at [virtual_networks_operations.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-network/azure/mgmt/network/operations/virtual_networks_operations.py) and you'll see methods such as `create_or_update()` within the `VirtualNetworksOperations` class.

Comment: Thanks david, But I am new to python and trying to create Virtual network using this code:                                                                            from azure.mgmt.network.operations import VirtualNetworksOperations
#Not sure what parameters have to pass here
vno = VirtualNetworksOperations()
result = vno.create_or_update('MyRG01','MyVN01')  Can u tell me Where to pass authorization details

Comment: I want sample code to create VN, Is there anyone who has tryed these things before?